# Input Box in Access VBA Won't Display

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a subroutine in Access VBA where I want to get some input from the user. I put the code in for an input box, but when I run it, no dialog box comes up for the user to enter input into.

I have something like this:

```
Dim Test As String

Test = InputBox("Enter Stuff Here:")
```

The code will run fine, but nothing happens. What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you run code at all, for example, post this into a module, not a form module, and run (f5) it:

```
Sub MyInput()
Dim Test As String

Test = InputBox("Enter Stuff Here:")
End Sub
```

As an aside, the best way of getting user input with MS Access is a form.

Comment: Hi, yes, it runs that way. If I put something like the following:  
  
`Dim Test As String`  
`Test = InputBox("Enter Stuff Here:")`  
`Msgbox "Is this working at all?"`  
  
The message box will pop up, but not the input box.

Comment: Does this solve your problem, or have you now got a new problem? If so, what is it?

Comment: No, it doesn't solve my problem. I'll probably just do a form, but I wish I knew why this didn't work.

Comment: I misread your comment. Have you got a version of your db that you can put on dropbox or such like so I can download it? The problem sounds quite strange.

Comment: You might like to check your references, compact & repair and decompile. Here is some more information http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html